# Which optimizer to use and when in neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, keras

I have gone through this quite [nice article on optimizers](https://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/). I know what each does. I've perused the web on when to use which optimizer. I know that generally the deep learning field says "just use Adam and problem solved."

But this isn't always the case! In fact, a lot of papers, especially in CVPR and NIPS are using the good old stochastic gradient descent, even in 2020 - well after the arrival and popularization of Adam. Consider this canonical publication on [inductive graph learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02216.pdf) in 2017 with currently ~2000 citations. It uses SGD.

In discussion with AI professors, they've told me that Adam can sometimes be unstable and you don't have as much control over it. So it is better to use SGD with learning rate update methods.

In fact, even Francois Chollet, the creator of Keras, in many of his blog posts doesn't use Adam. Take this post for example: [building autoencoders](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html). This article was written by him in 2016. Adam came out in 2014. I'm sure an expert such as Francois is fully aware of Adam since it is integrated into this Keras library. However, in that article he uses `adadelta` over `adam.`

So my question is as follows. If one were to specify a low starting learning rate to Adam, is the instability still such a problem? Why are researchers still turning to SGD and Adadelta? In other words, I somewhat repose the question asked [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/guidelines-for-selecting-an-optimizer-for-training-neural-networks): when to use which optimizer? Though I know what each does, I don't have an intuitive understanding on when to choose one optimizer over another.

Comment: I wouldn’t treat Keras tutorials on toy datasets as gold standards on choice of optimizers. On most toy datasets you could probably use any optimizer.

Comment: Recent paper on the matter: [Descending through a Crowded Valley - Benchmarking Deep Learning Optimizers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.01547). One of the main messages: "*the best out of a small set
of untuned optimizers — for example, ADAM and ADABOUND— frequently results in competitive overall performance, even compared to well-tuned optimizers.*" The best performance comes with tuning, but realistically trying a couple and picking the best is probably easier to document and faster to code.

Comment: @Tim Point well taken. I was getting at the fact that why is Adadelta even a consideration. Wouldn't Adam be the default every time if it's superior? If it isn't, then is there an intuition on when one's better than another? Of course things have to be verified empirically, but is there an intuition to start with?

Comment: @usεr11852 I hadn't seen that pub before, fantastic paper. Its final point about methods becoming lost in noise is definitely true.

Comment: @Christian: I am glad you like it, I thought it was very good too. And oh yes, *too true* about the noise. (+1) (If nobody answers anything, I will post that comment as a response.)